# Convert Access database to late binding to work with Access runtime

Tags: vba, ms-access, runtime

I wrote code in Access database 2016 contains functions and macros, then I move this file to share with some users that don't have Access Application so, I install Access runtime it works well but I face many problems with reference libraries. 
I decided to use late binding (by writing EarlyBinding = 0 in a database property of VBA editor)
and uncheck all references except two (I can't uncheck) and covert

```
Set appWord = New Word.Application
```

to

```
Set appWord = CreateObject(Word.Application)
```

note 1: I have a function to open Word document from Access form. 
note 2: I convert the database extension from .accdb to .accdr 
after I made changes in late binding and convert the previous statement no message error (for reference) appears but the function of open Word doesn't work.
is there a tool like Access runtime for Word? so I can't open for this reason?
below the code of this function:

```
Function fillWordForm()

Dim appWord As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim path As String
Dim myID As String

On Error Resume Next
Error.Clear

'Set appWord = CreateObject("word.application")
Set appWord = CreateObject(Word.Application)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
'Set appWord = New Word.Application
'Set appWord = CreateObject(Word.Application)
appWord.Visible = True
End If

'path = Application.CurrentProject.path & "\H_F.docx"

'path = "\\ubcdatacenter\Public\UBCIEDatabase\DOC\H_F.docx"
path = "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\UBC Database\H_F.docx"
If FileExists(path) = False Then
MsgBox "Template File Not Found", vbExclamation, "File Not Found"
Else
Set doc = appWord.Documents.Add(path, , True)
myID = DLookup("ID", "Exports_imports_Table", "[ID] = " & Me.ID)
With doc
.FormFields("BookID").Result = [ID]
.FormFields("Book_BC_date").Result = Me.date_BC
.FormFields("Book_AH_date").Result = Me.date_AH
.FormFields("Book_AH_date").Result = Me.date_AH
.FormFields("BookTopic").Result = Me.topic
.FormFields("BookProjectName").Result = Me.projectName
.FormFields("BookCompanyName").Result = Me.companyName
.FormFields("BookContent").Range.Text = Me.content

'Result = Me.content

appWord.Visible = True
appWord.Active
End With
Set doc = Nothing
Set appWord = Nothing

End If
End Function
```

this code to ensure that file is excite

```
Function FileExists(ByVal strFile As String, Optional bFindFolders As Boolean) As Boolean
    'Purpose:   Return True if the file exists, even if it is hidden.
    'Arguments: strFile: File name to look for. Current directory searched if no path included.
    '           bFindFolders. If strFile is a folder, FileExists() returns False unless this argument is True.
    'Note:      Does not look inside subdirectories for the file.
    'Author:    Allen Browne. http://allenbrowne.com June, 2006.
    Dim lngAttributes As Long

    'Include read-only files, hidden files, system files.
    lngAttributes = (vbReadOnly Or vbHidden Or vbSystem)

    If bFindFolders Then
        lngAttributes = (lngAttributes Or vbDirectory) 'Include folders as well.
    Else
        'Strip any trailing slash, so Dir does not look inside the folder.
        Do While Right$(strFile, 1) = "\"
            strFile = Left$(strFile, Len(strFile) - 1)
        Loop
    End If

    'If Dir() returns something, the file exists.
    On Error Resume Next
    FileExists = (Len(Dir(strFile, lngAttributes)) > 0)
End Function
```

what should also convert to make all code late binding?
**Editing**
**after Mathieu's changes**

Function fillWordForm()

```
Dim appWord As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim path As String
Dim myID As String

On Error Resume Next
Error.Clear

Set appWord = GetWordApp
If appWord Is Nothing Then
    'can't get ahold of Word.Application... now what?
    MsgBox "No thing :(((((((((((((("
    'Exit Sub
End If

appWord.Visible = True '<~ unconditional



'Set appWord = CreateObject("word.application")
'Set appWord = CreateObject(Word.Application)
'If Err.Number <> 0 Then
'Set appWord = New Word.Application
'Set appWord = CreateObject(Word.Application)
'appWord.Visible = True
'End If

'path = Application.CurrentProject.path & "\H_F.docx"

path = "\\ubcdatacenter\Public\UBCIEDatabase\DOC\H_F.docx"
'path = "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\UBC Database\H_F.docx"
If FileExists(path) = False Then
MsgBox "Template File Not Found", vbExclamation, "File Not Found"
Else
Set doc = appWord.Documents.Add(path, , True)
myID = DLookup("ID", "Exports_imports_Table", "[ID] = " & Me.ID)
With doc
.FormFields("BookID").Result = [ID]
.FormFields("Book_BC_date").Result = Me.date_BC
.FormFields("Book_AH_date").Result = Me.date_AH
.FormFields("Book_AH_date").Result = Me.date_AH
.FormFields("BookTopic").Result = Me.topic
.FormFields("BookProjectName").Result = Me.projectName
.FormFields("BookCompanyName").Result = Me.companyName
.FormFields("BookContent").Range.Text = Me.content

'Result = Me.content

appWord.Visible = True
appWord.Active
End With
Set doc = Nothing
Set appWord = Nothing

End If
End Function
```

---

```
Private Function GetWordApp() As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End Function
```

Comment: Make sure all modules say `Option Explicit` at the very top, then select "Compile VBAProject" from the "Debug" menu. Does it complain? If not, congratulations, you're all set. Note that `appWord.Visible = True` is conditional to there being an error with the `Set appWord = CreateObject(...)` statement, which is going to be a problem (unhandled error 91). Presumably you want `appWord.Visible = True` to be unconditional?

Comment: Also `Error.Clear` is weird, expecting `Err.Clear`, and even then, that would be no-op after an `On Error Resume Next` statement that's the first executable thing in the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> 'Set appWord = CreateObject("word.application")
> Set appWord = CreateObject(Word.Application)
> If Err.Number <> 0 Then
> 'Set appWord = New Word.Application
> 'Set appWord = CreateObject(Word.Application)
> appWord.Visible = True
> End If
> ```

Several things are wrong with this code. `CreateObject` wants a ProgID string, and you're giving it `Word.Application`, which shouldn't even compile (expecting "Object Required" error on the `.Application` member call, and "Variable not declared"<sup>1</sup> on `Word`). If it compiles, you've referenced the Word object library and need to remove it. The commented-out statement is well-formed.

Now `If Err.Number <> 0`, then `appWord` wasn't `Set`, and its reference is `Nothing`. That means if `CreateObject` fails, the code enters an error state *and remains in an error state for the remainder of the procedure*, because the error is never cleared, and error handling is never restored.

Take the error stuff into its own limited scope:

```
Private Function GetWordApp() As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
End Function
```

Now your procedure only needs to check if the function returned a valid object reference:

```
Set appWord = GetWordApp
If appWord Is Nothing Then
    'can't get ahold of Word.Application... now what?
    Exit Sub
End if

appWord.Visible = True '<~ unconditional
```

---

<sup>1</sup> assuming `Option Explicit` is at the top of the module, as it should be.

Comment: first of all thanks for your response, I am a beginner in programming so maybe my questions don't smart,  I edit my code as you said. without writing "exit sub" and without uninstall office applications, I just convert to .accdr and everything work well. when I am trying to add Word library, it displays to me there is "Error in loading DDL" so I can't make change in refrence, also what you mean by "Option Explicit" I didn't creat any module

Comment: after "if appword Is Nothing Then" statement I wrote a message and when I test my application on the machine doesn't have office application the message appears. I will edit my post with new changes.

Comment: I think you mean Form by "module" word. by default "Option Compare Database" written at the top of every form code. after this line, I wrote "Option Explicit". is that OK? or should I delete the first line?